# Can't call inherited method if I overload it with a different subclass argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, vtable

I have these base classes to be extended and the goal was to provide some default implementation for unhandled events in the subclass.

```
struct Event {};

struct State {
    void handle_event(const Event& e) {
        std::cout << "State - generic event\n";
    }
};
```

An example of a subclass implementation:

```
struct FlipSwitch : public Event {};
struct OtherEvent: public Event {};

class Light : public State {
public:
    void handle_event(const FlipSwitch& e) {
        std::cout << "Light - FlipSwitch event\n";
    }
};
```

If I call:

```
Light *light = new Light();
light->handle_event(FlipSwitch());    // Works fine.
light->handle_event(OtherEvent());    // error: no matching function for call to
                                      //  ‘Light::handle_event(OtherEvent)’
```

If I define the default implementation on the subclass or add `using State::handle_event;` it fallbacks accordingly.

I expected that if the compiler didn´t find any function with 'OtherEvent' that would fallback to the generic defined in the base class just like it does when it's not inherited. I didn't expect the subclass to hide the method with a method with a different signature.

Comment: By declaring a function with the same name in the child class, you *hide* the base-class declaration. It's not an overload, and not an override. The simplest solution is to pull in the base class declaration into the scope of the `Light` class with the `using` directive.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't technically accurate. I know that is a solution but because I want to expose this as a library, I wanted to provide a default out of the box without exposing internals. I guess there's no way around it.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Once hidden, the parent class functions aren't looked for at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by fixing your inheritance scheme and using dynamic casting in order to dispatch event processing to the right handler:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// make Event polymorphic by adding at least one virtual function
struct Event {
    virtual ~Event() = default;
};

// making handle_event virtual to properly override it
struct State {
    virtual void handle_event(const Event& e) {
        std::cout << "State - generic event\n";
    }
};

struct FlipSwitch : public Event {};
struct OtherEvent : public Event {};

class Light : public State {
   public:
    // void handle_event(const FlipSwitch& e) {
    // override handle_vent
    virtual void handle_event(const Event& e) override {
        // use dynamic dispatch
        // NB using pointer so that dynamic_cast fails by returning nullptr, not
        // exception
        if (dynamic_cast<const FlipSwitch*>(&e)) {
            std::cout << "Light - FlipSwitch event\n";
        } else {
            State::handle_event(e);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Light* light = new Light();
    light->handle_event(FlipSwitch());  // Works fine.
    light->handle_event(
        OtherEvent());  // also works fine
    return 0;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/K7Gjv4z6c)

First make `handle_event` a proper virtual function so that a inherited object will call its implementation.
It will use `Event` object of any concrete type.
Then, in the overrided version, use `dynamic_cast` to try to cast the `Event`object to its actual class.
Besides, I use `dynamic_cast` on pointer, not reference, si that, if the requested type is not the correct one, it will return `nullptr`, not throw an exception.
For `dynamic_cast` to work, `Event` must be a polymorphic type, that is to say, a type that can be inherited. A way to tell that to the compiler is to declare at least one virtual function, here the destructor.
If no valid type is recognised, I fall back to the default behavior, for instance, one that is implemented in the base class.
*Et voilà*